# Alternative to azure accelerated networking

Tags: azure

I am looking for an alternative to azure accelerated networking.  Usecase remains the same.  I wish to have better response times on my VM which has support for hyperthreading. My concern is around cpu core underutilization brought forth by the accelerated networking requirement of maintaining 4 CPUs.  The application doesn't even use up 2 cores.  Let me know if there are any possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Receive Side Scaling (RSS) is one known option...

If the Windows VM supports Accelerated Networking, enabling that feature would be the optimal configuration for throughput. For all other Windows VMs, using Receive Side Scaling (RSS) can reach higher maximal throughput than a VM without RSS. RSS may be disabled by default in a Windows VM.
On Linux VMs, it is enabled by default.